# Adding a variable in the global scope to a specific class - Python

Tags: python-2.7, class, global

```
class PhysCon:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tfrz = 273.15                   
        self.cwat = 4188.0                   
        self.cice = 2117.27                  
        self.rhowat = 1000.0
```

I want to add "PhysCon().ke = 2.9". I calculated "ke" in another function that occurs after "PhysCon". How do I add "ke" to the "PhysCon" class and still have it be connected to the entire class when PhysCon() is called?

Comment: Kindly, it could be better to add the code in a snippet, than show-it by a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I fixed it.

Comment: @DavidBonan What if you add `ke = 2.9` right after `class PhysCon:`, before `def __init__(self):`? You can then do `PhysCon().ke` to get the value and `PhysCon.ke = 123` to change it for all subsequent instances of the class.

Comment: I guess the issue is that I am creating new variables in another file, importing that file/function into this one, and then I want to be able to take some of the new variables and add them to the Class PhysCon. Is there a way to use "add" or "setattr"? The other file uses some of the variables from the original class.